# JSLint error on return statement

Tags: javascript, return, jslint

Hello all I am currently running JSLint on my files to clean them up.
I have file which have some private function and public function and i am making public function accessible to out side file using a variable.

```
Util.data = (function() {
    var privar; 
    pri_func1 = function() { 
       //do something
    },
    pri_func2 = function() { 
       //do something
    }

    return {  // JSLint error

         pub_fun1: function() {
               //do something
            },
         pub_fun2: function() {
               //do something
            }
    }

})();
```

Now out side my this file i am accessing these function likes this

```
Util.data.bub_fun1();
Util.data.bub_fun2();
```

Its working fine. But now the from problem is that the JSLint is giving me an error on the return statement

**#1 Unexpected 'return'.
    return { // Line 78, Pos 9**

So I want to ask that is there a way to remove JSLint error in a way that i don't have to change my other files and can call these function as it is that is

```
Util.data.bub_fun1();
```

Thanks alot any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine. You just need to take care of little things. In this case `;` is missing after declaring 'pri_func2'.

```
pri_func2 = function() { 
   //do something
};
```

This should be enough for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Util = {};
Util.data = (function() {
    var privar,
        pri_func1 = function() { 
           //do something
        },
        pri_func2 = function() {
           //do something
        };

    return {  // JSLint error
         pub_fun1: function() {
               //do something
            },
         pub_fun2: function() {
               //do something
            }
    };
})();
```